# Python 3.1.2 Interpreter lacks shell feaures on OS X when compiled from source

Tags: command-line, osx-snow-leopard, python

The version of Python provided by default in Snow Leopard makes available some features of the bash shell (i.e., command history, keyboard shortcuts, etc.) to its interactive interpreter. After compiling Python 3.1.2 from source and installing, I've noticed that the interactive interpreter for the compiled Python 3.1.2 lacks many of those same features (command history isn't available, can't clear the screen using Ctrl+L, can't navigate command lines using Emacs style shortcuts). Is there a configure option I missed to get this working? Has anyone gotten these features working after compiling from source?

*NOTE: I'm compiling from source and installing into my home directory because I don't have admin privileges on this machine. I used the following commands to compile and install:*

```
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.compiled/python-3.1.2
> make
> make install
```

Comment: Isn't it early for python 3.x? I was going to suggest ipython as alternative, but noticed that they don't have a python 3.x port yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build libedit or readline first.